# How to handle '00' in JSON results in JS or Coldfusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, coldfusion-10

I am not sure how to word this so I will just be direct.

I am using Jquery with ajax to update a select box when another select box changes. All is working according, except, when the JSON returns, the fail method fires rather than the done method.

After looking through everything, I determined that the returning JSON is invalid.

The JSON IS

```
{
    "COLUMNS": ["DESCRIPTION", "COMPUTED_COLUMN_2"],
    "DATA": [
        ["Test; Job PD", 11],
        ["Test 2", 10],
        ["Test 3", 00],
        ["Test 4", 20]
    ]
}
```

The value for Test 3 is 00. This should actually be string '00'. However, the parser, which is SerializeJSON in ColdFusion seems to return 00 as a number. This causes the JSON conversion to fail and fires the fail method. This only occurs on iOS and a Mac.

My question becomes, how do I enforce a value in JSON to be a string value and not a numeric value?

My environment is:

OSX Mavericks
Chrome
ColdFusion 10
CFWheels 1.1.8

Comment: Put quotes around it. You cannot tell JSON to treat a value as a string, you have to actually modify the JSON so it *is* a string, typically at the point when you encode your data, so that the values are strings.

Comment: What data type does the query have at `COMPUTED_COLUMN_2`? I don't understand why `SerializeJSON()` would output `00` for an actual `0`.

Comment: Except 00, remaining canbe used.  `00` is considered as `0`, better go with @meager's idea.  It is easy to convert back a string to integer.

Comment: If it is a string, you need to make it a string!

Comment: when in doubt...run JSON through jsonlint.com to validate it

Comment: I'm assuming this is coming from a database, since his serialized object is in the same format as a coldfusion query. With that in mind, simply converting the number to a string might not be so simple. In railo this is handled by converting `00` to `0` if it is currently a number, which stands to reason if you converted them all to a string using sql, it would instead keep it as a string. But i would expect it to already be a string in sql since it is `00`.

Comment: Things you should try: Cast them to string using sql. | iterate over the query, generating a new query with the correct datatypes | iterate over the query, creating an object structure while converting the numbers to strings | add a dataFilter to your ajax request that replaces `00` with `'00'`

Comment: It comes from a varchar column in a database. That is why it is a string. Also, JSONLint does fail the validation, that is how I determined the 00 is not a valid number.

Comment: So the serialization is incorrectly converting them to number, and doing a terrible job at that.

Comment: @KevinB dataFilter did not work; case to string in sql did not work as well; iterating over the query works, but seems inefficient to me

Comment: Agreed, that's very inefficient. I can say though, i am unable to recreate this in railo. Can you try this to see if it recreates your issue? http://pastebin.com/8MxDYtT8

Comment: Does Railo and CF10 use the same JSON encoder?

Comment: I do get the same error with your code from pastebin

Comment: The response was: {"COLUMNS":["DESCRIPTION","COMPUTED_COLUMN_2"],"DATA":[["Test: JobPD",11],["Test 2",10],["Test 3",00],["Test 4",20]]}     The 00 was converted to a number.

Comment: Serialize JSON in coldfusion is just flawed i guess. At that point i would include an external cfc to do the serialization instead. http://tojson.riaforge.org/ Makes me glad i use railo, with how much i use json.

Comment: What version of ColdFusion 10 are you running? I found a bug regarding this issue and it is supposedly fixed (although we have seen that you can't always trust the bug statuses). [ColdFusion 10.0  -  Bug 3338825](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3338825) Fixed In Build 285090

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using js regex replace in a data filter to replace the special case.

```
response.replace(/(00)/, '"00"');
```

The quotes are important as if you simply replace "00", it will re-serialize it back to a number.

UPDATE:

This issue is resolved from Adobe in ColdFusion update 11. Big thanks to @Miguel-F for pointing this out.

Comment: Did you update and verify that it works for you? Just curious because I don't always trust their bug statuses.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, 00 as a number in JSON is not valid - Check under "number" here: http://www.json.org/
As meagar writes in his comment above, you need to encode it as a string.

You can also encode it as 0 (since that is the integer value), and take that special case into account when parsing your data.

Comment: Unfortunately, I require the value to be 00 as a string, not a number. I use SerializeJSON in CF10 to generate the JSON so I do not have any control over the encoding.